# How to interpret and define action plan when my pay cheque is getting delayed every month?

Tags: salary

I am working as Senior developer for Indian based Organization. The organization size is 25. We have 2 offices one at India and another one in UK. We have Managing director at each office who will take care of HR, Project Management, Finanace and Operations Management solely.

I have joined one year back and I am getting my pay cheque last working day of the month. But past 3 months the pattern was changed and slowly we are getting pay cheque little late. And this delay in pay cheque constantly increasing a day or 2 in every month. Below are the sequence in chronological order

- August 2014: Our MD requested for cooperation as there are some problem getting funds from UK to release pay cheque and release pay cheque on Sept-4
- September 2014: Our MD told that UK office still not released funds and he assure that he will fight to get the issue fixed and release Pay cheque Oct-6
- OCtober 2014: Our MD told that, the issue is due to that company due some of clients who didn't clear their invoices and UK team will work on this seriously and released pay cheque on Nov -10
- November 2014: Our MD arranged conference meeting with UK MD. UK MD assures that issue will get fixed in couple of months and released pay cheque on Dec 12

I feel like there is pattern going on. I don't know how to interpret it. As it is holiday season it is very tough to get another job quickly. The Employement and labour law in India is not as strict as in USA or other countries. It is more favorable to investors than employers

How to interpret and define action plan when my pay cheque is getting delayed every month?

Comment: Rule #1: Don't mess with my paycheck. This is a sign of financial difficulties. Time to move on.

Comment: @Jim G, I am not asking for advise or what to do. My question is "How to interpret and define my own plan of action?". I disaggree with the closing reason

Answer (score 16):

Appears they are having money problems.  Time to start looking for another job.  Next you might have some checks bouncing so get to the bank as fast as you can you when you do get paid.  I don't know about India but in my US state if you have an account at the same bank your check clears first.  I have had problem customers that I open an account at their bank and even cash the check payroll day as some times they will borrow to cover payroll.

Comment: Seen this happening before. This is **the** advice.

Comment: messing with the date I am supposed to get paid is the first sign of financial trouble.  Once and its ok, some one made a mistake.  Three months in a row?  Time to be the first rat off the shinking ship.

Comment: 3 months in a row where the payment is getting later and later. Sounds to me like they're paying out whatever is at the bottom of the barrel at this point.

Comment: If they had any plan for fixing this they'd be telling the employees about it, in an effort to keep people from starting to look elsewhere. That they haven't means they don't. Draw your own conclusions; mine would be to do whatever it takes in your country to quit and start looking elsewhere. You've got the perfect answer to "why do you want to change jobs" -- "I liked the work, but I can't live on promises."